# How can i retrieve a simple document from firestore through react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the fallowing code but it lists every document in firestore, which modifications should i make to list only one document for example with the id: gNfFy0uEsk5OvrZOfkGm

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import firebase from '../config/Fire'

function useTimes(){
    const [kullanici,setTimes] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('kullanici')
            .onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
                const newTimes =snapshot.docs.map((doc)=>({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data()
                }))

                setTimes(newTimes)
            })

    },[])

    return kullanici
}

const Main = () => {
    const kullanici =useTimes()

    return(

        <div>
        {kullanici.map((kullanici)=>
            <li key={kullanici.id}>
            <div>kullanıcı:{kullanici.nick}\nid:{kullanici.id}</div>
            </li>
        )}
        </div>

    )}


export default Main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('kullanici')
    .doc('gNfFy0uEsk5OvrZOfkGm')
    .onSnapshot((doc)=>{
        const newTimes = doc.data()

        setTimes(newTimes)
    })
```

I recommend checking out the Firebase documentation on [listening for realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), as this is covered quite well there.